# Clean up broken links to Google Plus

Tags: discussion, editing

There is a bunch of information for webmasters that used to live on Google Plus.  Google employees such as John Mueller posted there.  We have about 150 posts that link to Google plus:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Aplus.google.com

Google plus is no longer available and those links are broken.  They should be removed or the links converted to a cached copy from the internet archive.

I'd appreciate any help with this project.   As usual with mass edit projects, please just do a few at a time to prevent flooding the front page.

Comment: Ugh. Let's start chipping away....

Comment: Which do you or the mods prefer? Cache or removed? Or even just removing the `http://` and placing (depreciated) or some other notation? Cheers!!

Comment: Linking to the cached version would be most useful for users if a cached version can be found.